Bloc implementation in flutter
i'm new to flutter-bloc
I want to achieved selection of a multiple options from a list ,
i achieved the result myself but it contain some issues
like
navigation after success and loading on action button on AppBar and list items in body changes when state is changing,
and want to clear the all selected topics after submitting the form or press the back button of the screen
how to do it in proper way
UI
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          BlocBuilder<BlogBloc, BlogState>(
            builder: (context, state) {

              if (state is BlogInitial) {
                return IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                      context.read<BlogBloc>().add(
                            BlogUploadEvent(
                                posterId: posterId,
                                title: titleController.text.trim(),
                                content: contentController.text.trim(),
                                image: image!,
                                topics: state.topics),
                          );
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.done_rounded,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<BlogBloc, BlogState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is BlogFailure) {
            log(state.error);
            showSnackbar(context: context, message: state.error);
          }
          if (state is AuthSucess) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
              RouteName.blogPage,
              (route) => false,
            );
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              child: Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                  .......
                  .........
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          'Technology',
                        .....
                          'Entertaintment'
                        ]
                            .map(
                              (value) => BlocBuilder<BlogBloc, BlogState>(
                                builder: (context, state) {
                                  if (state is BlogInitial) {
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        context
                                            .read<BlogBloc>()
                                            .add(SelectTopicsEvent(value));
                                      },
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            horizontal: 8),
                                        child: Chip(
                                          label: Text(value),
                                          color: state.topics.contains(value)
                                              ? const WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                                                  AppPallete.gradient1)
                                              : null,
                                          side: state.topics.contains(value)
                                              ? null
                                              : const BorderSide(
                                                  color: AppPallete.borderColor,
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    return Container(
                                      child: Text("asd"),
                                    );
                                  }
                                },
                              ),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  

below code is blog_bloc.dart
class BlogBloc extends Bloc<BlogEvent, BlogState> {
  List<String> selectedTopic = [];  //<===== empty list for add topics 
  final UploadBlog uploadBlog;
  BlogBloc(
    this.uploadBlog,
  ) : super(BlogInitial(topics: const [])) {
    on<BlogUploadEvent>(_uploadBlog);
    on<SelectTopicsEvent>(_selectTopic); ////<===== event for add topics 
  }

  void _selectTopic(SelectTopicsEvent event, Emitter<BlogState> emit) {
    if (selectedTopic.contains(event.topic)) {
      selectedTopic.remove(event.topic);
    } else {
      selectedTopic.add(event.topic);
    }
    emit(BlogInitial(topics: List.from(selectedTopic)));
  }

  void _uploadBlog(BlogUploadEvent event, Emitter<BlogState> emit) async {
    emit(BlogLoading());
    final res = await uploadBlog.call(
      .........
    );
    res.fold(
      (l) => emit(BlogFailure(l.message.toString())),
      (r) {
        emit(
          BlogSucess(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

below code is blog_event.dart
part of 'blog_bloc.dart';

@immutable
sealed class BlogEvent {}

final class SelectTopicsEvent extends BlogEvent {
  final String topic;

  SelectTopicsEvent(this.topic);
}

final class BlogUploadEvent extends BlogEvent {
  final String posterId;
  .........
  .........
  final List<String> topics;

  BlogUploadEvent(
      {required this.posterId,
     ...
});
}

below code is blog_state.dart
part of 'blog_bloc.dart';

@immutable
sealed class BlogState {}

final class BlogInitial extends BlogState {
  final List<String> topics;

  BlogInitial({required this.topics});
}

final class BlogLoading extends BlogState {}

final class BlogSucess extends BlogState {}

final class BlogFailure extends BlogState {
  final String error;

  BlogFailure(this.error);
}


emit BlocInit state again to clean the selectedTopics again
